# Close server and client socket connection at the same time

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

I have a created a client and server using sockets, Hangman game where the client sends the letter input to the server and so on. When the player wins or loses, the server terminates. I want the client to terminate at the same time as well before displaying "Enter letter: ". Is there a way of doing this?

Here is a part of my client code:

```
do {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter letter: "); 
        BufferedReader UserIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        input = UserIn.readLine();
        pw.println(input);
        System.out.println(SocketIn.readLine());
        System.out.println();

        while(SocketIn.ready()) {
            System.out.println(SocketIn.readLine());
        }   

    } while (socket.isConnected());
```

Comment: The server response should contain a command like "finished" and "continue" to control the client behavior. Closing the socket is not fast and reliable enough. The socket state is recognized on next read/write action by the client.

Comment: @Konrad My server is going through a "while (true)" loop. The server closes when the player wins or loses in a if/else statement. Can you give an example when you say "finished"? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `ready()` test and recode your loop like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = SocketIn.readLine()) != null)
{
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

`ready()` can't tell you about end of stream. Neither does `isConnected()`.